# Google Cloud App Engine - Default Storage Buckets

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When I create a new application on Google Cloud App Engine, these buckets in Google Storage show up as well (where yyy is my app's name):

```
eu.artifacts.yyy.appspot.com
staging.yyy.appspot.com
yyy.appspot.com
```

What do they do exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official documentation [Using Cloud Storage for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-cloud-storage#default_bucket):

> When you create an app, App Engine creates a default bucket that
> provides the first 5GB of storage for free. The default bucket also
> includes a free quota for Cloud Storage I/O operations. See Pricing,
> quotas, and limits for details. You will be charged for storage over
> the 5GB limit.
>
> The name of the default bucket is in the following format:
>
> **project-id.appspot.com**
>
> App Engine also creates a bucket that it uses for temporary storage
> when it deploys new versions of your app. This bucket, named
> **staging.project-id.appspot.com**, is for use by App Engine only. Apps
> can't interact with this bucket.

**eu.artifacts.yyy.appspot.com** is your [container registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) bucket

> Your Container Registry bucket URL will be listed as
> gs://artifacts.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com or
> gs://[STORAGE-REGION].artifacts.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com, where:
>
> [PROJECT-ID] is your Google Cloud Console project ID. Domain-scoped
> projects will have the domain name as part of the project ID.
> [STORAGE-REGION] is the location of the storage bucket: us for
> registries in the host us.gcr.io **eu for registries in the host
> eu.gcr.io** asia for registries in the host asia.gcr.io

Answer (score 1):

Each of these buckets are for App Engine build and temporary artifacts.

Example: App Engine also creates a bucket that it uses for temporary storage when it deploys new versions of your app. This bucket, named staging.project-id.appspot.com, is for use by App Engine only. Apps can't interact with this bucket.